# recursive download from webline with account and password

Tags: wget, download

Is it possible to download zip files from a website with login account and password?

I tried

```
wget --recursive --no-parent -nd https://*edu/pages/access/search.jsp
```

However, not being able to download all the zip files. got a copyright message below.

```
!DOCTYPE html, COPYRIGHT NOTICE
Copyright (c) 2016  Scott C. Neu and Arthur W. Toga
```

What should be done next? The files are really huge to download to my local computer.

Comment: Advice to newcomers: If an answer solves your problem, please accept it by clicking the large check mark (✓) next to it and optionally also up-vote it (up-voting requires at least 15 reputation points). If you found other answers helpful, please up-vote them. Accepting and up-voting helps future readers. Please see [the relevant help-center article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

You should try to render [wget](/questions/tagged/wget) like a human browser:

```
wget --user-agent='Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0' --recursive --no-parent -nd https://*edu/pages/access/search.jsp
```